# Set Imageview Position and rotation

Tags: android

So I'm doing some rotations and Translates on an imageview. As i understand it, the imageview is not truly in a new location after either of these and you have to actually move it there after the animation is done. So the imageview i'm trying to move around is called token and it is set in its original position and `token.getLocationOnScreen( tokenPos );` has its starting position. After a move or translation i call `resetToken` to handle the move or rotation. This seems to accomplish the desired result half the time... not sure what i'm doing wrong but its inconsistent with it facing the way i want it to.

```
public void resetToken() {   
    //Decode Image using Bitmap factory.
    Bitmap bMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(token.getDrawingCache());

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(0);

    //move the token to the spot it needs to be in
    //after an animation the token is not really
    //in the new spot
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(token.getWidth(), token.getHeight());
    lp.setMargins(tokenPos[0], tokenPos[1], 0, 0);

    //Create bitmap with new values.
    Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, token.getWidth(), token.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    token.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
    token.setLayoutParams(lp);
    //put rotated image in ImageView.


    moveCounter = moveCounter + 1;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it this way.

```
public void resetToken() {   

    Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.robo);
    Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bmResult); 
    tempCanvas.rotate(currentMapDirection, token.getWidth(), token.getHeight());
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, null);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(token.getWidth(), token.getHeight());
    lp.setMargins(tokenPos[0], tokenPos[1], 0, 0);

    token.setLayoutParams(lp);

    token.setImageBitmap(bmResult);


}
```